# How to format CSV file for importing multiple files to Google Cloud AutoML Translate?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I am trying to use the Python Client Library to add multiple files to a dataset I have created for AutoMl Translate. I was unable to find a good example for the csv file that is to be used. Here is the link to their [Python Client Library example code](https://cloud.google.com/translate/automl/docs/datasets#training-data) to add files to a dataset.

I have created a csv in a bucket of the following form:

```
UNASSIGNED,gs://<bucket name>/x,gs://<bucket name>/y
```

Where I am trying to add two files called x and y.
and I get the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.GoogleAPICallError: None No files to import. Please specify your input files.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I formatted the csv file. Each file I want to add needs to have its own line,

The correct csv file would look like this:

```
UNASSIGNED,gs://<bucket name>/x
UNASSIGNED,gs://<bucket name>/y
```